Firebase cloud function deploy can't find my python module in artifacts repository
I have a working set of firebase cloud functions using the Python admin SDK.   I'm now trying to pull out shared code so that different applications' functions can use the same code library.  It works locally - I used "py -m build" and hatchling to make a distribution.  I created a gcloud service account and gave it admin credentials for my repository. I used twine to upload it to a gcloud artifacts repository. I successfully install it back from the repository onto my Windows machine, and it runs nicely.
But now, I'm trying to deploy my cloud functions.  I put my new package into my requirements.txt, but when I run 'firebase deploy', I consistently get this error:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement MY_LIB>=0.0.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for MY_LIB>=0.0.1. For more details see the logs at 

I'm having trouble debugging this.   I have a few things I don't really know:

How can I tell the firebase deploy command which repository to use?  Does it search all the python ones repositories my project?

Is there any easy way to just list my repository during the build process to see in Gcloud cloud build logs if it can access it?

If I set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS on my local windows machine, will Google's cloud build machine have the required credentials to access the repository?


Appreciate any help!

I figured it out.    requirements.txt is the main channel to instruct the build process it seems, and so one has to add
--extra-index-url https://us-central1-python.pkg.dev/<PROJECT ID>/<REPO>/simple.
Of course, I had left out the 'simple' at the end.
